# What is the equivalent method of installTrigger.install in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In firefox `InstallTrigger.install` is used to download `.xpi` file stored on the local FileSystem.

Which method is used to download the `.crx` file in chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation is what you are looking for.